# Código do Unity não compila

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MovingObject {

    public int pointsPerFood = 10; // Numero de pontos cada vez que pegar comida.
    public int pointsPerSoda = 20; // "" pegar Soda.
    public int wallDamage = 1; //Quanto o player causa de dano no muro.
    public float restartLevelDelay = 1f; //Tempo em segundos para reiniciar o level.

    private Animator animator;// usado para armazenar o animator do player.
    private int food; //Armazena a comida do player no level atual.

    //Override do start MovingObject
    protected override void Start ()
    {
        animator = GetComponent <Animator>();

        //pega a quantidade de vida total
        food = GameManager.instance.playerFoodPoints;


        base.Start ();

    }

    //e chamado qunado o player fica inativo ou desabilitado.
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        //Quando o player for desabilitado armazenar a quantidade de comida no GameManager.
        GameManager.instance.playerFoodPoints = food;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update () 
    {
        //so vamos fazr alguma coisa se for o turno do player
        if (!GameManager.instance.playerTurn)
            return;

        int horizontal = 0;
        int vertical = 0;

        //pega o input do input manager horizontal e arredonda para inteiro
        horizontal = (int) (Input.GetAxisRaw ("horizontal"));

        //pega o input do input manager vertical e arredonda para inteiro
        vertical = (int) (Input.GetAxisRaw ("vertical"));


        //verificar se o personagem se move somente em uma direçao
        if (horizontal != 0) 
        {
            vertical = 0;

        }

        //verificar que existe um valor nao zero em alguma direçao
        if (horizontal != 0 || vertical != 0) 
        {
            //chama a fuçao AttempMove passando o parametro generico wall
            AttemptMove<Wall> (horizontal, vertical);

        }



    }

    //Override do MoveObject
    protected override void AttemptMove <T> (int xDir, int yDir)
    {
        //toda vez que ele se mover ele consome comida
        //food = food -1;
        food--;

        base.AttemptMove <T> ( xDir, yDir);

        RaycastHit2D hit;

        CheckIfGameOver ();

        GameManager.instance.playerTurn = false;

    }

    //override do MovingObjects
    protected override void OnCantMove <T> (T component)
    {
        Wall hitWall = component as Wall;

        //quando se tenta mover contra um muro vc ataca ele
        hitWall.DamageWall (wallDamage);

        //dispara gatilho para trocar a animaçao do player atacando 'playerchop'
        animator.SetTrigger ("playerChop");

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other);
    {
        //checa se e a saida.
        if (other.tag == "exit");
        {
            invoke ("Restart" , restartLevelDelay);

            enabled = false;

        }
        else if(other.tag == "Food")
        {
            //adicionar a quantidade de comida
            food += pointsPerFood;

            Other.GameObject.SetActive(false);

        }
        else if(other.tag == "Soda")
        {
            //adicionar a quantidade de comida
            food += pointsPerSoda;

            Other.GameObject.SetActive(false);

        }
    }



    private void Restart ()
    {

        Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);

    }

    //perder comida quando player apanhar do zumbi
    public boid LoseFood (int loss)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger ("playerHit");

        food -= loss;

        CheckIfGameOver ();

    }




    //verificar se o player esta sem comida, se sim gameover.
    private void CheckIfGameOver ()
    {
        //verificar comida do player
        if (food == 0)
        {
            //chama o game over do GameManeger
            GameManager.instance.GameOver ();

        }

    }










}
```

[image: erro]

Comment: Já dá para ver que tem vários erros puramente de digitação. Revise porque você não seguiu certinho. A não ser que o tutorial esteja todo errado, aí você não deveria seguir ele. Se ainda tiver dúvidas que vão além dos erros de digitação, coloque o código aqui e os erros. Tudo como texto mesmo. Imagens são complicadas pra gente analisar e ajudar. Copie e coloque o que está no IDE e não uma foto do IDE.

Comment: Podes [edit] a pergunta e juntar o código? assim como está é dificil de ajudar...

Comment: coloquei o codigo agora... :3

Comment: Editei agora a pergunta para facilitar, perdão a galera que tentou ajudar e não conseguiu entender...

Comment: Quais são os erros apresentados?

Comment: Parece que é só erro de digitação. Podemos fechar a pergunta?

Comment: Para fazer uma nova pergunta, abra uma nova, não edite a mesma pergunta. E coloque informações suficientes para as pessoas poderem te ajudar, caso contrário a pergunta será fechada anates de ser respondida.

Comment: Outra dica: coloque um titulo que descreva seu problema. "Ajuda com script" serve de título pra todas as perguntas do site.

Comment: Entendi, vlw galera resolvido. Esse foi meu primeiro post aqui, desculpe qualquer equivoco da minha parte. Ajudaram bastante. :3

Comment: @RannySantos Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Se você tirar os `;` nestas duas linhas já deve resolver todos os problemas:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other) {
    //checa se e a saida.
    if (other.tag == "exit")
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/UnitySyntax.cs).

Se tiver outros problemas, informe para eu atualizar a resposta.